# How to use Dynamic and Setting inside a DynamicModule?

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, user-interface

Consider an image (`img`) as

[image]

Using the following code I can dynamically change the value of `t` and see the updated components.

```
Manipulate[
 bin = MorphologicalBinarize[img,{t[[1]],t[[2]]}];
 Colorize[MorphologicalComponents[bin]],
{t, 0, 1}, ControlType -> IntervalSlider
]
```

I can switch to `DynamicModule` in the following way:

```
DynamicModule[{},
 bin = Dynamic@MorphologicalBinarize[img, t];
 c = Dynamic@Colorize[MorphologicalComponents[Setting@bin]];
 {c, Dynamic@IntervalSlider[Dynamic[t]]}
 ]
```

So far this is fine. However, I have several other lines of codes followed by this inside `DynamicModule` and every time I need to apply `Dynamic` to get the updated result and when one result is to be applied to the next line I need to use `Setting`.

Do I need to use `Dynamic` at each operation and followed by `Setting` or is there any better way to avoid this?

Comment: No, you do not need, `DynamicModule[{},
 c = Dynamic[
   bin = MorphologicalBinarize[img, t];
   Colorize[MorphologicalComponents[bin]]
   ];
 {c, Dynamic@IntervalSlider[Dynamic[t]]}]`